# Does anyone have the correct link to treewidth.com?

Tags: algorithms, trees

Several [posts](https://mathoverflow.net/q/31545) (and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41651/941)) on StackExchange sites like MO have some link-rot. For example, I've been looking into tree decomposition and keep coming across references to [treewidth.com](http://www.treewidth.com), but the link appears to be dead.  Does any one have an update on this site to share?

Comment: Have you tried to contact the author of that answer directly? Maybe he can help you.

Comment: @SebastianGoette I don't have enough reputation to ask that in the post (add a comment, that is). So, I thought I ask my own question. You seem like a pro on MO and you posted your web-site on your profile, but not all users do that.

Comment: I'm still a noob to here, in the case of @BartJansen, the link to his site is dead as well. Is there a good way to contact the author directly other than via the comments?

Comment: Sorry, I did not check the link on BartJansens profile, just that there was one. Anyway, welcome to MO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In situations like this, https://archive.org helps.

In this case check:

https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.treewidth.com/

There are many snapshots over time, though the downloads fail for me.

Searching for "libtw.jar", showed the same site at:
http://treewidth.com/treewidth/index.html

and libtw.zip is downloadable.